# ¿Qué elemento utilizar para qué función tenga?

Tags: html

A la hora de crear plantillas, tengo la extraña y podrida duda de qué elemento utilizar para qué funcionalidad tenga, como es el caso de la imagen de una marca de alguna empresa con un enlace a la página principal.

*Considerando que el interior del elemento `a` sea la imagen y que solo queramos mostrar la imagen de la marca de la empresa, sin adiciones (`nav`).*

```html
<a>
  <div></div>
</a>
```

```html
<a>
  <img>
</a>
```

```html
<a>
  <div>
    <img>
  </div>
</a>
```

Sé que puede ser ambiguo, pero imagino que el W3C tendrá una explicación para estos casos particulares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo tiene un por qué y todos los elementos actuan de una forma muy peculiar, por ejemplo

```
<a href="home.html">
  <img src="foo.png">
</a>
```

Debe haber la combinación de una o más etiquetas para conseguir un funcionamiento específico si necesidad de meter Javascript

En este ejemplo, la etiqueta `<a>` se está utilizado para anclar a otra página, e `<img>` para cargar una imagen X. Esto debido a que ni la etiqueta `<a>` tiene un atributo `src` ni `<img>` tiene un atributo `href` y es por eso que debes combinar la funcionalidad

De lo contrario podríamos quedarnos con algo así

```
<img onclick="redirect()" src="foo.png">
<script>
  function redirect(){
    location.replace("home.html")
  }
</script>
```

Aquí tiene mucho que ver lo que quieras conseguir y que tanto quieras escribir, a veces no hay una respuesta exacta para X circunstancia.

Comment: Lo único que puedo responder a esto es... Touché.